# An Inequality Related to Absolute Values

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality, absolute-value

There exist two very known inequalities related to absolute values of complex numbers $x$ and $y$, namely, $|x|-|y|\leq |x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$.

However, I would like to find a kind of reverse inequality with possible constants and with some (which can be useful) hypothesis. In fact, my question is:

**Question.** Does there exist positive constants $k$ and $r$, such that for any complex numbers $x$ and $y$, with $|x|>|y|>2$, the estimate
$$
|x|-|y|\geq k(|x-y|)^r
$$
holds?

Any suggestion?

Note that if $x$ and $y$ are positive real numbers, then $x=y+\delta$, for some positive $\delta$. Then, 
$$
|x|-|y|=\delta\geq \delta=k(|x-y|)^r,
$$
for $k=r=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y = -x + \delta$ where $\operatorname{arg}x = \operatorname{arg}\delta$, then $|x| - |y| = |\delta|$

$\forall k,r > 0\ \ k |x - y|^r \ge k$ if $|x - y| \ge 1$

$\therefore \exists \delta \ \text{s.t} \ |\delta| < k$

$\therefore \forall k,r > 0\ \exists x,y\ \text{s.t.} |x| - |y| < k |x - y|^r$ where |x| > |y| > 2

Comment: Note that in the statement of question is written that ||>||>2, so y cannot be -x

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that initially. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @Jean (forgot the ping)

Answer (score 1):

No such inequality exists. Take $x=1+\epsilon$ and $y=-1$. The inequality fails for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small (whatever $k$ and $r$ may be).

Comment: Note that in the statement of question is written that ||>||>2, so y cannot be -x.

Comment: @Jean Thanks for the comment. I have edited my answer.